# Empty lookup table vs non-matching lookup table (lookup transform)

Tags: ssis, lookup

Is empty lookup table the same as non-matching lookup table in lookup transform?

What would be the result if no row redirection is configured?

1. an empty result set or
2. package failure at the lookup transform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get #2: Package failure. It would not be able to find the row in the lookup table (since it's empty).

Edit: I should say that if you set the Error Configuration to `Ignore Failure`, you will get an empty rowset.